# Gradle 4.4 and 4.6 do not use dependencies from dependent projects

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.1

I have 2 gradle projects A and B

In project A I have

```
dependencies {
    ext {
        support_library_version = '26.1.0'
    }
    implementation "com.payu.india:payu-sdk:4.4.1"
    implementation "com.payu.magicretry:magicretry:1.0.4"
    implementation "com.payu.custombrowser:payu-custom-browser:6.1.1"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${support_library_version}"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_library_version}"
}
```

In project B I have

```
implementation project(':A')
```

For some reason project B reports unable to find symbol for all `com.payu.*` imports.

After I upgraded gradle to 4.4 I had to copy all the needed `implementation` from project A to project B. What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 Answers posted on gradle issues [here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/4927).

**1**

This doing exactly what it's supposed to. That's the difference between the api and implementation dependencies when you use the java-library plugin:

`implementation` dependencies are "internal", so do not leak to downstream consumers `api` dependencies are, on the other hand, exposed transitively because they participate in the API surface
So either you need to add an explicit `implementation` dependency on A, to explain that you too need the dependencies, or they should be using api. We cannot determine it automatically for you.

**2**

As the name says, `implementation` dependencies are implementation details and are not available for downstream projects to compile against. If a dependency should be part of your `api`, you should use the `api` configuration